# 2002 Chevy Impala part name

Tags: chevrolet, part-identification, impala

What's the name of this part? I notice that it's smoking in my car..

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It's called EGR valve